# Can software for Ubuntu Desktop work on Ubuntu touch unmodified?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I have software that works on Ubuntu 12.10 Desktop. Would it run also on Ubuntu Touch?

Specifically, I'm trying to use [OpenCFU](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencfu/) on a Ubuntu tablet. I just want to know if it would work; whether it would be able to satisfy all the dependencies like GTK etc. using the terminal.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You've tagged your question with `application-development`, but your question doesn't show anything about development. Are you just trying to get the application running or are you asking this from a software developer point of view?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: No.

The long answer is: Yes, if the app was written in Qt 5 or HTML, and was capable of running on the limit screen size and interacting with touch input and on-screen-keyboard, then it would run.  But most apps written originally for the desktop won't meet that criteria.

The even longer answer is: This is why we developed the Ubuntu SDK, it's a toolkit designed to allow apps to be developed for desktops, phones and tablets (and TVs).  It has resolution-independence built it, it support multiple display servers already, and it's being designed to adapt appropriately between touch and keyboard/mouse inputs.  Eventually we hope that the majority of Ubuntu's apps will work seemlessly across all of our supported form factors, and the Ubuntu SDK is how we plan to get there.

Comment: its a c++ program... and its not written for touch input . will it work?